# Referencing Page Item in SQL LIKE Query - Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I am passing parameters to another page that displays a table of the values based off of the parameters passed into the page.

It passes in 3 successfully - City, address, and zipcode and displays the exact match. However, I need the zipcode to not be exact and instead be ok with passing in the first 5 numbers and not the 5 numbers including the last 4 digits.

```
ADDRESS = :P16_ADDRESS
and CITY = :P16_CITY
and ZIPCODE LIKE ':P16_ZIPCODE%'
```

That is the code I tried in the WHERE clause, but it is still trying to display the exact match or possibly even the word ":P16_ZIPCODE", but I cannot tell. :P16_ZIPCODE is how to reference the page item in SQL.

Any alternate solutions would also be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: `ZIPCODE LIKE :P16_ZIPCODE || '%'`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 ADDRESS = :P16_ADDRESS
 and CITY = :P16_CITY
 and ZIPCODE LIKE SUBSTR(:P16_ZIPCODE, 1, 5) || '%'
```